# showSnackbar not working on post login API

Tags: flutter, api, http

why isnt the snackbar working? ive put snackbar for the credentials which are not in the database but when wrong user name is passed the snackbar is not working and help me with the wrong codes. [snack bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wrYb.png)

```
        Future<void> login(String email, String password) async {
    Map request = {'email': email, 'password': password, 'device_name': 'dell'};
    try {
      final response =
          await http.post(Uri.parse('http://192.168.1.98:8081/api/login'),
              body: jsonEncode(request),
              headers: {
                "Content-Type": "appliction/json",
              },
              encoding: Encoding.getByName("UTF-8"));
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print(response.statusCode);

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        // ignore: unused_local_variable
        var data = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
        // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
        Navigator.push(context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const FrontPage()));
      } else if(response.statusCode == 422){
        // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
            .showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text("Invalid Credentials")));
      } else if(response.statusCode == 404){
        // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
            .showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text("Page not found")));
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

```
ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        login(emailController.text, passwordController.text);
                        if (_formkey.currentState!.validate()) {
                          return;
                        } else {
                          return;
                        }
                      },
                      child: const Text("Login"),
```

Comment: Which context are you using? Show full code

Comment: is that print(response.statusCode); printing correct status code ?

Comment: and the ohter 422 and 404 status code is also not working only 200 statuscode works @Autocrab

Comment: Seems like you're using wrong context. Post full `build`  method please

Answer (score 0):

use this plugin **bot_toast: ^4.0.3** , while using by this plugin not need any **context** . This is the main advantage of this plugin so you can add this any where ever you want

This is the link : https://pub.dev/packages/bot_toast

initialize and simply call this

```
BotToast.showText(text:" You'r massage")
```